# Container exits immediately in detached mode

Tags: docker

I suppose a docker container run at background could be held alive. But the truth is container always exists immediately in detached mode.

```
docker run -d busybox
ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
42d4db933e8a        busybox:latest             /bin/sh             11 seconds ago      Exited (0) 11 seconds ago                       sharp_sammet
```

How to persist this session without faking doing some loop jobs to prevent being closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just simply run `docker run -dt busybox` instead.
The option "t" means tty(stdio/stdout) will be held and thing works as you expected.

Comment: How would I specify this option in case of docker-compose?